# Tensorflow TextVectorization layer: How to define a custom standardize function?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, text

I try to create a custom standardize function for the [TextVectorization layer in Tensorflow 2.1](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.1/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/TextVectorization) but I seem to get something fundamentally wrong.

I have the following text data:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([
    "I am a sentence.",
    "I am another sentence!"
])
```

### My Goal

I basically want to lower the text, remove punctuation and remove some words.
The default standardize-Function of the TextVectorization layer (`LOWER_AND_STRIP_PUNCTUATION`) lowers and removes punctuation, but afaik there is not way to remove whole words.

(**If you know a way to do so, an alternative approach to mine as described below is of course also very much appreciated**)

---

### An example that is working

First, find an example of a **working** custom standardiazion function [from the tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings)

```
def custom_standardization(input_data):
  lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
  stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, '<br />', ' ')
  return tf.strings.regex_replace(stripped_html,
                                  '[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '')
```

when I pass it to the `TextVectorization` and adapt in on `my_array`, it works just fine

```
vectorize_layer_1 = TextVectorization(
    output_mode='int',
    standardize=custom_standardization,
    )

vectorize_layer_1.adapt(my_array)  # no error
```

---

### The custom function that is not working

However, my custom standardization keeps raising an error. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence

my_array = np.array([
    "I am a sentence",
    "I am another sentence"
])

# these words should be removed
bad_words = ["i", "am"]

def remove_words(tokens):
    return [word for word in tokens if word not in bad_words]

# this is the normalization function I want to apply
def my_custom_normalize(my_array):
    tokenized = [text_to_word_sequence(str(sentence)) for sentence in my_array]
    clean_texts = [" ".join(remove_words(tokenized_string))
                     for tokenized_string
                     in tokenized]
    clean_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(clean_texts)
    return clean_tensor
    
my_vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    output_mode='int',
    standardize=my_custom_normalize,
    )
```

However, once I try adapting, I keep running in an error:

```
my_vectorize_layer.adapt(my_array)  # raises error
```

```
InvalidArgumentError: Tried to squeeze dim index 1 for tensor with 1 dimensions. [Op:Squeeze]
```

And I really do not understand why. In the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/core_preprocessing_layers/text_vectorization/) it says:

> When using a custom callable for standardize, the data received by the callable will be exactly as passed to this layer. The callable should return a tensor of the same shape as the input

I thought maybe thats what is causing the error.
but when I look at the shapes, everything seems correct:

```
my_result = my_custom_normalize(my_array)
my_result.shape  # returns TensorShape([2])
working_result = custom_standardization(my_array)
working_result.shape # returns TensorShape([2])
```

I am really lost here. What am I doing wrong? am I not supposed to use list comprehensions?

Comment: I think it would be better to remove the words by using regex with ```tf.strings.regex_replace```. I have never used ```TextVectorization``` in keras, but looking at the source code, this seems to be the line that is causing the error: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/preprocessing/text_vectorization.py#L569

Comment: Just an idea. Try replacing the body of ```my_custom_normalize``` with this: ```return tf.strings.regex_replace(my_array, "(?i)i|am", "")```

Comment: In reality, there will be more words to remove, (>200), so putting them into a regex would be quite cumbersome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def custom_standardization(input_data):
    lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
    stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, "<br />", " ")
    stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(stripped_html,r'\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?', ' ')
    stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(stripped_html, r'@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)', ' ' )
    for i in stopwords_eng:
        stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(stripped_html, f' {i} ', " ")
    return tf.strings.regex_replace(
        stripped_html, "[%s]" % re.escape(string.punctuation), ""
    )
```